# French newspaper dataset

Tags: data-request, french

I'm looking for a large dataset containing french newspaper articles associated with a newspaper category.

The categories should match those of [mediatopics](http://cv.iptc.org/newscodes/mediatopic).
It can be in any format.

I would like to use this kind of dataset to train a model to categorize automatically newspaper articles.